# How can I get a user's activity/status?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot that can copy the name and pfp of a user, but I can't figure out how to read a user's status.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure the Presence Intent is enabled for your Bot in https://discord.com/developers/applications -> Your Bot Name -> Bot

Second, it depends what status, your question is unclear. It can be their custom set status, presence status, game activity, or spotify activity.
For presence, [Discord.js Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/PresenceStatus) States `<GuildMember>.presence.status` can return 4 options as a string.

Comment: Thanks! I had it enabled on the developer portal but forgot to enable it in code whoops